# High availability Search implementation in PHP+MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

I am building a new website that sells apparel. I made most of them by myself and I want to create a website to sell them.

I want an advanced search that will allow the user to search with different criterias:

- color
- size
- shape
- material (metal, plastic etc...)
- fabric type
- cost
- type (gloves, scarf, etc...)

So I have the following shcema:

```
product:
id int(10) unsigned not null primary key auto_increment
name varchar(200),
price float(5,2),
color_code_1 int(5) default 0,
color_code_2 int(5) default 0,
color_code_3 int(5) default 0,
color_code_4 int(5) default 0,
color_code_5 int(5) default 0,
etc...
```

The problem I have now is, if I search for 1 color (example red) and the color code for red is in the `color_code_5` the search will not return any results. since my script look for 1 color, therefore only look for color_code_1.

so my question is, is there a better to do this:

```
//4 = red

... WHERE color_code_1 = 4 OR color_code_2 = 4 OR color_code 3 = 4 OR color_code 4 = 4 OR color_code 1 = 5 OR
```

the problem is if I add more colors, i will have to change all my queries and i think that is not very fast to execute?

what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Create a new table called apparel_colors. Link the ID of the product with the ID of the color.

Comment: @DavidBélanger how? Comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common best practice is to create a table that holds all colors (dictionary table). Then use that table based on the relationships you want to build by adding the corresponding foreign keys. In your case you need many colors for each product thus a many to many relationship is required. To achieve this you need to create a many to many table and associate products with many colors.

```
product:
id int(10) unsigned not null primary key auto_increment
name varchar(200),
price float(5,2),

color:
id int(10)
name varchar(100) /*e.g. red*/

product_color:
color_id int(10)
product_id int(10)
```

The idea is, as you have already realized, that you may have many colors, as well as other attributes for example manufacturers. In that case you create a table (dictionary tables) holding that information and add foreign keys to your product table if it is a one to many relationship or to another many to many table if a product has many manufacturers or vice versa .

Comment: That is a common best practise, but it won't solve the problem if you want to have multiple colors for a product.

Comment: @GolezTrol can you please elaborate on this? Do you have any references? It is a completely normalized way of holding data. I have been using it , as well as other engineers, for a long time building systems and it works perfectly well. I'll try to post some references.

Comment: You are right about normalization, but in this case a product can exist with multiple colors. You don't solve that problem by creating a color_id in the products table. If you want to normalize colors to a separate table (which is indeed a good practise), you will need an extra junction table which holds the various colors for each product. As you can see, the table in the question contains 5 color columns, which is basically a very un-normalized version of an m:n relationship.

Comment: @GolezTrol you are correct on that and i will edit my answer, was a bit quick the relationship is indeed a many to many relationship and a many to many table is required.

Answer (score 1):

Store the colors in a separate table.

```
product_color
  product_id int,
  color int
```

You can then perform a select like this:

```
select
  id, name, price
from
  product p
where
  /* Select all products that have at least the color red */
  exists (
    select 'x' 
    from product_color pc
    where pc.product_id = p.id
      and pc.color = 1)
```

In case of appararel, though, you might want to create a separate table that stores a combination of properties, since you might not have 'green' in all sizes as well, so you might get an `product_variation` table that contains multiple records, each one describing size, material and a color. From there you can even split it further (for instance, allow multiple colors and materials per variant), but you might not need that now.

Comment: why a subquery instead of JOIN?

Comment: Well, in this case, you will probably model the database in such a fashion that you can only have a color once for each product, so in this particular query you could do that. But the query will grow, and before long you will risk returning a product twice. For instance if you want to have all products available in red or green. In my query you can easily do that, while with a join you will have to add `distinct`. `exists` is pretty fast, though, and the database should use its indexes properly with a query like this.

Comment: I currently use the process you described, using JOINS and DISTINCT for multiple search values (red or green). So are you saying it is faster/more efficient to do it with a subquery? Its always been my understanding to use JOINS over subqueries whenever possible

Comment: I cannot say that it is faster or more efficient, but it is more clear what is going on, therefor easier to extend the query. Also, you're less likely to introduce errors. Distinct will work fine, but if you for whatever reason add one of the columns of product_color to the select list, you will still introduce the duplication. I've actually seen this happen in production code, so I'd rather stay on the safe side and don't write a query that looks like you can just add a field to the selection. Not saying that `distinct` is evil, but it's close. ;)

Comment: Good to know, not sure it applies to my situation, but def applicable here. I deleted my answer...thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't need to do that. In some cases a join might even be faster and in some cases you might need that extra speed at the expense of readibility. Besides, your answer was the most upv... the least downvoted. ;-)