# Create the query for multiple product property

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Yesterday I had an issue:

[High availability Search implementation in PHP+MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078540/high-availability-search-implementation-in-phpmysql)

after implementing melc's solution, I needed to change my query and i have this issue:

so I have:

```
product:
id int(10) unsigned not null primary key auto_increment
name varchar(200),
price float(5,2),
type int(10)

attribute:
id int(10)
name varchar(100) /*e.g. red, small, large, green, metal, plastic etc...*/

product_attribute:
attribute_id int(10)
product_id int(10)
```

So I have all my custom attributes like color, size, type of metal/plastic etc... in the "attribute" table. I have so far, over 500 and 50 types (size, color, shapes etc...)

So, if I want to get all the red products i do:

```
select * from product_attribute
where attribute_id = 4 (for reg)
```

Now, if I want all the product that matches this: red and blue, small, plastic

i tried to do:

```
select * from product_attribute
where attribute_id = 4 and attribute_id = 5 and attribute_id = 10 and attribute_id = 38
```

but this return nothing, so I tried:

```
select * from product_attribute
where attribute_id = 4 OR attribute_id = 5 OR attribute_id = 10 OR attribute_id = 38
```

but then I get attributes that does not correspond to what I want!

what can I do ? is my DB tables wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the UNION:

If they choose 2 properties:

```
SELECT * FROM product_attribute where attribute_id = 4
UNION
SELECT * FROM product_attribute where attribute_id = 8
```

Or 3:

```
SELECT * FROM product_attribute where attribute_id = 4
UNION
SELECT * FROM product_attribute where attribute_id = 8
UNION
SELECT * FROM product_attribute where attribute_id = 37
```

You get the idea.

This will get all the results, now you have to group them by product id, so

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM product_attribute where attribute_id = 4
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM product_attribute where attribute_id = 8
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM product_attribute where attribute_id = 37  
) AS allItems
INNER JOIN product ON (allItems.product_id = product.id)   
GROUP BY allItems.product_id
/* ORDER BY price  */
```

This will return the list of products you need

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [JOINS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), if you want to find products that are both Red AND Plastic, because I am guessing your Product_Attribute Table saves multiple attributes as separate rows...
For Example if you need to get products that are Red and Plastic

```
SELECT a.product_id, a.attribute_id, b.attribute_id
FROM product_attribute a
    JOIN product_attribute b JOIN a.product_id = b.product_id AND a.attribute_id <> b.attribute_id
WHERE a.attribute_id = 4 AND b.attribute_id = 10
```

This would get you products with 2 attributes, similarly if you need products with more than 2 attributes you will have to use more JOINs...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a rat's nest of joins:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM product p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 4  UNION
  SELECT 5  UNION
  SELECT 10 UNION
  SELECT 38
  EXCEPT
  SELECT attribute_id
  FROM product_attribute
  WHERE product_id = p.product_id
)
```

For each product, take the set of desired attributes, subtract the set of that product's attributes, and if there is nothing left over, then that product must have all the desired attributes.

Also, instead of using the select-union to declare your set of desired attributes, you could use some other query or a table-valued parameter.  This way, you compare an arbitrary number of attributes.